# Can't invoke server's method from client - Error: An unexpected error occurred invoking 'SignIn' on the server

Tags: reactjs, .net, signalr, azure-cloud-services, azure-signalr

I'm build a project using SignalR.
As Front I'm using .Net Core, as Back I'm using React.
So in my localhost the project is working, but when i deploy this project i get an error.
In azure I have created:
2 web application - one used for cliend, and the other one for server.
1 Azure SignalR service (i tested it online and it worked)
1 Azure SQL Database

So when i try to invoke Method it now working and show me this error. Someone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that my Database was empty... the migration did not upload, Update the database solved it.

Answer (score 0):

- Please check this [***ASP.NET Core SignalR connection
  troubleshooting*** | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  which helps to check  errors
  that can occur when trying to connectto an ASP.NET Core SignalR hub.
- One common cause is that app enforce HTTPS by calling
  UseHttpsRedirection in Startup, or enforces HTTPS via URL rewrite
  rule.

> So If it is the cause try to change the URL on the client side from
> "http" to "https". like > `.withUrl("https://xxx/HubName")`

- Also please go through [c# - Could not connect to Azure SignalR Hub -
  Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493434/could-not-connect-to-azure-signalr-hub) And check if the signalR url  endpoint for client
  is correctly given

  ```
  var signalrUrl = "https://myazuresignalr.service.signalr.net/client/?hub=yourHubName"
  ```
- Please note that sending the exception this way  to the client is
  insecure .So try to  either throw a `HubException` or set
  EnableDetailedErrors on the server.See [***HandleErrors*** when :Use
  hubs in ASP.NET Core SignalR | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#handle-errors-2)

**Reference:**

- [Invoke hub's method which throw ArgumentException, client gets
  HubException: An unexpected error occurred · Issue azure-signalr ·
  GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/488)